# Connecting Google Apps Script to a Parse Database (ScriptDB Replacement)

Tags: google-apps-script, parse-platform, nosql

With the recent news that ScriptDB is being deprecated, I'm searching for a suitable replacement. My particular use case is that I'm running Google Apps Script under Google Forms to process and store data relevant to the function of the form.

I've been through Google's migration guide ([link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/script-db)), and I'm trying to connect a Google Apps Script running under a Google Form to a Parse Database ([link](https://www.parse.com/products/core)). I've tried both methods listed on the migration guide (URL Fetch Service and ParseDB Library), and I can't get either to work correctly. I was able to write to the Parse Database using ParseDB, but the query function isn't working as expected. I also tried using the parseCom library from the Excel Liberation site (sorry, I'm out of links for this post, apparently), but that didn't work very well either.

I'm most interested in using Google's URL Fetch Service to connect to a Parse database, as that seems to be my most flexible option (i.e. to let me share data between forms - something I really couldn't do with scriptDB), but I feel like I'm in over my head just a bit. I'm open to other options as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What problems are you having with the ParseDB library specifically?

Comment: I was able to use the ParseDB libary to add items to the database and to count the number of items in the database. However, db.query did not function as expected with ParseDB - it returned quite a bit of HTML that didn't seem to indicate (to me, at least) what the problem was.

Comment: What did your query look like?

Comment: I didn't document the query output. I re-wrote the scripts I was using, and I'm getting intelligible responses to my queries now. Chalk it up to me being a noob, I guess. I'm still interested in connecting via UrlFetchApp, but when I try to fetch via UrlFetchApp, the URL throws an unspecified error. I'm trying to fetch via the Parse REST Api (https://www.parse.com/docs/rest) using this command: UrlFetchApp.fetch(https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/classes/myClassHere) [with my data in place of the placeholders, obviously].

Comment: @jcastle0 How did you manage to get it to add items to the database/count? Would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: @stan I'm trying, but apparently the code is too long for me to post, so I'm linking to the code in a Google Doc. This particular code would be used to save a person's name, ID, and eye color to Parse. It's just a dummy script I set up while testing: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iF0BLvAbGygFniYWEJAe2af8UDV65dwQmlmj0VSCw0Y/edit

Answer (score 0):

I have the same 'query' problem using the MongoLab database as overstack-asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024299/google-appscript-urlfetchapp-wont-allow-mongolab-db-queries-using-rest-api). I thought Parse might work as an alternative, but then I saw this post having the same 'query' problem.

If you run your query from the browser directly to Parse it will probably work fine, just as it does for me using the MongoLab database.

Consequently, I strongly suspect the problem is in the URLFetchApp.fetch() function itself, not the Parse (nor MongoLab) database functions.

Comment: I can query MongoLab with UrlFetchApp.fetch() just fine. I can't get it to write to the MongoLab db though. Just fetch this url below with the variables matching up to what's in your instance.

var allDocUrl = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/' + db + '/collections/' + collection + '?apiKey=' + apiKey;

Comment: Your above url returns the whole collection (or table); it's not a query, such as:

  var url = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?q={"active": true}&apiKey=';
  var oDataObject = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());

Comment: The'q' part is the json query object which UrlFetchApp doesn't accept as an input argument to fetch().

Comment: I got it to write to MongoLab using app script, as follows:

  oDataObject = JSON.stringify(oDataObject);
    var url = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/'+ MWO_GetDbName() +'/collections/my-coll' + '?apiKey=' + MWO_GetDbKey();
    var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "contentType": 'application/json',
      "payload": oDataObject
    };
    var sResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();

Comment: to add the query you just add the cleanQuery variable below after the "&q=" portion of the URL:
var query = { "key" : { "_id" : 1 } };
var cleanQuery = encodeURIComponent(Utilities.jsonStringify(query));

Comment: If I have to fetch the entire table and iterate through it, 'matching variables' as you suggest, then that's fine if the table is small, but not good if the table > 1000 records (MongoDb's record return max). Most tables are greater than 1000 records, hence you must use the query function above.

Comment: Thank you, Stan! I thought the fetch() function was automatically encoding already, but no; now, yes, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have found to be the best way to query results using UrlFetchApp and Parse.

```
function query(key,value) {
  var properties = getKeys();
  var appId = properties.appId;
  var restApi = properties.restApi;
  var class = 'TestObject';
  var url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/' + class;

  var query = 'where={"' + key + '":"' + value + '"}'

  var encoded = encodeURIComponent(query);
  var queryUrl = url + '?' + encoded;

  var options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : {
      "X-Parse-Application-Id": appId,
      "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": restApi,
    }
  }

  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl, options);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this out when I get a chance!

Answer (score -2):

I am also looking for this.

As a temp store ScriptDb has been very helpful. Sheets simply does not have the elegance of beautiful coding as in ScriptDb